# Using CreateNode and SetAttribute methods in Powershell script to update XML file is adding implicitly prefix parameters d3p1 and d4p1

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file that I need to update using a Powershell script. For this update I need to add some nodes and to set some attributes for those nodes.

Here, I'll give you an example about how I'm doing it:

```
[xml]$SuiteFile = Get-Content -Path $SuiteFilePath
$SuiteNamespace = "http://www.google.com"
$ExecutablePackageNode = $SuiteFile.CreateNode("element", "ExecutablePackage", $SuiteNamespace)
$ExecutablePackageNode.SetAttribute("Name", $SuiteNamespace, "SuppressExternals")
$SuiteFile.Save("$SuiteFilePath")
```

I'm expecting to see the XML line updated this way:

```
<ExecutablePackage Name="SuppressExternals" xmlns="http://www.google.com">
```

But instead, it gets updated like this:

```
<ExecutablePackage d3p1:Name="SuppressExternals" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.google.com">
```

It seems it's adding the 'd3p1' prefix parameter implicitly, even though I don't specify prefix parameter in my methods. Can someone please let me know why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that .Net is adding the `"d3p1:"` prefix to the attribute `Name` is that it **must** do so in order to honor your requirement that the attribute be added to the `"http://www.google.com"` namespace.  If you don't want that you should create the attribute without specifying a namespace.

A more detailed explanation follows.  As stated in the [XML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting):

> The namespace name for an unprefixed attribute name always has no value.

(This is in contrast to an unprefixed XML **element** which will be in the default namespace.)

When you do

```
$ExecutablePackageNode.SetAttribute("Name", $SuiteNamespace, "SuppressExternals")
```

you are calling the [`XmlElement.SetAttribute(SetAttribute (string localName, string namespaceURI, string value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_XmlElement_SetAttribute_System_String_System_String_System_String_) method:

> Sets the value of the attribute with the specified local name **and namespace URI**.

Thus you are specifically requesting that the attribute be created in the `$SuiteNamespace` namespace.  But since an unprefixed attribute is never in a namespace, .Net must automatically generate some prefix to use to specify the namespace.  This is what you are seeing.

If you do not want the attribute to be created in `$SuiteNamespace`, just call [`SetAttribute (string name, string value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_XmlElement_SetAttribute_System_String_System_String_):

```
$ExecutablePackageNode.SetAttribute("Name", "SuppressExternals")
```

And you should get an unprefixed `Name` attribute.